# Reversing an array in Cython

Tags: numpy, cython

## Problem

This is related to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951813/reverse-a-2d-numpy-array-with-multiple-slice-objects/59953404#59953404), about reversing a 2D numpy array column-wise, with random indices per row. For example.

```
np.random.seed(0)

arr = np.repeat(np.arange(6)[np.newaxis], 100000, axis=0)
m, n = arr.shape
indices = np.sort(np.random.rand(m, n).argsort(1)[:,:2], axis=1).astype("int32").

# reverse 
for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(reverse):
    arr[idx, i:j+1] = arr[idx, i:j+1][::-1]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# `arr`                        # `indices`                       # `output`
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],     array([[3, 4],                    array([[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],            [0, 3],                           [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],            [2, 4],                           [0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5],
       ...,                           ...,          -->                 ...,
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],            [3, 5],                           [0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],            [1, 4],                           [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])           [0, 2]])                          [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5]])
```

I experimented with a Cython version of this function, given below.

```
cpdef int[:,:] reverse_indices(int[:,:] arr, int[:,:] indices):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t idx, N = arr.shape[0]
        int i, j

    for idx in range(N):
        i, j = indices[idx, 0], indices[idx, 1]
        arr[idx, i:j + 1] = arr[idx, i:j + 1][::-1]

    return arr
```

But I found that this was "only" ~8 times quicker than a pure python version (47ms vs. 375ms). I found that line `arr[idx, i:j + 1] = arr[idx, i:j + 1][::-1]` was especially slow. I removed this and replaced with the following to perform the reverse operation.

```
    for idx in range(N):
        i, j = indices[idx, 0], indices[idx, 1]

        while i < j + 1:
            arr[idx,i], arr[idx,j] = arr[idx,j], arr[idx,i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    return arr
```

This solution was ~157 times quicker than the python version (2.4ms vs. 375ms).

## Question

1. I found that even, without any reversing (`[::-1]`), i.e. `arr[idx, i:j + 1] = arr[idx, i:j + 1]`,  has a similar effect on performance. Why does slicing a section of an array have such a significant effect, vs. indexing a single element?
2. Is there a better way to reverse a section of an array/list in Cython?

Comment: I think the the vague answer is "Cython/Cython memoryviews are generally optimized for handling individual elements, not slices". That doesn't really answer exactly what's slow, but your current version is probably pretty good.

Comment: Thanks @DavidW for your comment! I'm guessing this also applies if you use np.ndarray instead of a memoryview?

Comment: I think so. It's probably easy enough to test, but I'd be surprised if it made much difference.

Comment: Yeah just tested and it’s a bit slower on my machine.